How to increase cell height and make the grid with responsive

The default cell height is 25px but I want it to be 30px.
Tried to increase it like this and it gets increased

.rg-cell.rg-number-cell, .rg-cell.rg-formula-cell, .rg-cell.rg-text-cell, .rg-cell.rg-header-cell { height: 30px !important; }
but the cell data remained at the same place because each cell has top: 25px for rowindex = 1 and like wise for rowindex = 2 it is top: 50px.
Therefore, along with the height the top is need to be increased but not sure how to do that.
Used saas variables as well and tried to applied $cell-padding but didn't work.
https://reactgrid.com/docs/4.0/6-styling/2-sass-variables/

Need to make the width of the grid responsive as per the column counts. And is it possible to fix first 2 columns and then add scroll bar to the rest.

